# Como ejecutar dos consultas en MYSQL desde netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Quisiera por favor que me ayuden.¿Como ejecutar dos consultas a una misma tabla desde netbeans?. Aquí las consultas:

```
insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, hora_entrada, hora_salida, 
numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo, j_codigo) select 
codigo_personal, substring(dia,1,1) AS dia,  min(hora_inicio), 
MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT 
seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as malla, 
1,1
from tb_horariodocentes_org
where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='D' 
GROUP by codigo_personal,dia
ORDER by 2,3,5


insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, hora_entrada, hora_salida, 
numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo) select codigo_personal, 
substring(dia,1,1) AS dia, min(hora_inicio), MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT 
seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as malla, 
tb_periodo.codigo
from tb_horariodocentes_org, tb_periodo
where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='N' and 
tb_periodo.codigo='2'
GROUP by codigo_personal,dia
ORDER by 2,3,5
```

Aquí lo que estaba intentando:

```
public void PasarDatosHorarios()
{

    String consulta="insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, 
   hora_entrada, hora_salida, numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo, 
   j_codigo) select codigo_personal, substring(dia,1,1) AS dia,  
   min(hora_inicio), MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT 
   seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as 
   malla, 1,1\n" +
                    "from tb_horariodocentes_org\n" +
                    "where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='D' \n" 
                     +
                    "GROUP by codigo_personal,dia\n" +
                    "ORDER by 2,3,5";

    String consulta1="insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, 
   hora_entrada, hora_salida, numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo) 
   select codigo_personal, substring(dia,1,1) AS dia, min(hora_inicio), 
   MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT 
   seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as 
   malla, tb_periodo.codigo\n" +
                    "from tb_horariodocentes_org, tb_periodo\n" +
                    "where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='N' and 
    tb_periodo.codigo='2'\n" +
                    "GROUP by codigo_personal,dia\n" +
                    "ORDER by 2,3,5";
    try 
    {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(consulta);
        if(rs.next())
        {
             Statement nuevostmt = cn .createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = nuevostmt.executeQuery(consulta1);
            while(rs2.next()) 
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hola Vero, antes de nada te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y conseguir tu primera medalla, por otro lado estaría bien que miraras [ask] para poder formular las preguntas de la manera que estamos acostumbrados. Y por último, también pedir que pongas el código que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Amigo ya le agregue el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso es muy sencillo. Solo debe crear un `Statement` y agregar las consultas con el método `addBatch(String query)`:

```
Statement st = cn.createStatement();
st.addBatch(consulta);
st.addBatch(consulta1);
st.executeBatch();
```

Si quieres conocer más sobre este tema, googlea este criterio de búsqueda: "ejecucion en batch jdbc".

Comment: Gracias por contestar!!!!... probare lo que me dice....